# Linear independence of continuous functions in a neighborhood

Tags: calculus

Let $f_{1},f_{2}\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m}$ be two continuous
functions and let $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a point such that $f_{1}\left(a\right),f_{2}\left(a\right)$
are linearly independent. That is
$$
\gamma_{1}f_{1}\left(a\right)+\gamma_{2}f_{2}\left(a\right)=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\gamma_{1}=\gamma_{2}=0
$$
I would like to know if there is also a neighborhood of $a$ such
that $f_{1},f_{2}$ are linearly independent there. That is to show
the existence of a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
with $\left|x-a\right|<\delta$ we get that $f_{1}\left(x\right),f_{2}\left(x\right)$
are also linearly independent. Meaning
$$
\gamma_{1}f_{1}\left(x\right)+\gamma_{2}f_{2}\left(x\right)=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\gamma_{1}=\gamma_{2}=0
$$
Is this right? How can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If $m = 2$:

consider $$g(x)=det(f_1(x),f_2(x))$$
Since $g(a) \ne 0$, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $0 \notin I=]g(a)-\epsilon, g(a)+\epsilon[$

Since $I$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(I)$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$\forall x \in g^{-1}(I), g(x)\ne 0 \iff f_1(x), f_2(x) \text{ independent}$$

### If $m = 1$:

$f_1(a)$ and $f_2(a)$ cannot be independent

### If $m > 2$:

There exists $(e_2, .., e_m)$ such that $(f_1(a), f_2(a), e_2, .., e_m)$ is a base of $\mathbb{R^m}$

Consider $$g(x)=det(f_1(x),f_2(x), e_2, .., e_m)$$ and apply the same processus.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the Gram-Determinant of $f_1(a)$ and $f_2(a)$, that's here
$$\|f_1(a)\|^2\|f_2(a)\|^2-\langle f_1(a),f_2(a)\rangle^2$$
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant.  If it's non-zero at $a$, due to continuity it will be non-zero in a neighbourhood of $a$.